# jackson-dataformat-csv: Mapping number value without POJO

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file using `jackson-dataformat-csv` and I want to map the numeric column to the Number java type.

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true)
    .addColumn("firstName", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
    .addColumn("lastName", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
    .addColumn("age", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
    .build();

CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();  

MappingIterator<Map<String, Object>> mappingIterator = csvMapper
        .readerFor(Map.class)
        .with(schema)
        .readValues(is);        

while (mappingIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, Object> entryMap = mappingIterator.next();
    Number age = (Number) entryMap.get("age");
}
```

I'm expecting `entryMap.get("age")` should be a `Number`, but I get `String` instead.

My CSV file:

```
firstName,lastName,age
John,Doe,21
Error,Name,-10
```

I know that `CsvSchema` works fine with POJOs, but I need to process arbitrary CSV schemas, so I can't create a new java class for every case.

Any way to parse CSV into a typed `Map` or `Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_records.html#using-records) for this sort of thing. It's faster and way more flexible:

```
CsvParserSettingssettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //configure the parser if needed
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

for (Record record : parser.iterateRecords(is)) {
    Short age = record.getShort("age");
}
```

To get a typed map, tell the parser what is the type of the columns you are working with:

```
parser.getRecordMetadata().setTypeOfColumns(Short.class, "age" /*, and other column names*/);

//to get 0 instead of nulls when the field is empty in the file:
parser.getRecordMetadata().setDefaultValueOfColumns("0", "age", /*, and other column names*/);

// then parse
for (Record record : parser.iterateRecords(is)) {
    Map<String,Object> map = record.toFieldMap();
}
```

Hope this helps

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 4):

Right now it is not possible to configure `Map` deserialisation using `CsvSchema`. Process uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer` which right now does not check schema. We could write custom `Map` deserialiser. There is a question on GitHub: [CsvMapper does not respect CsvSchema.ColumnType when using @JsonAnySetter](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/60) where `cowtowncoder` answered:

> At this point schema type is not used much for anything, but I agree
>   it should.

### EDIT

I decided to take a look closer what we can do with that fact that `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer` is used behind the scene. Implementing custom `Map` deserialiser which will take care about types would be tricky to implement and register but we can use knowledge about `ValueInstantiator`. Let's define new `Map` type which knows what to do with `ColumnType` info:

```
class CsvMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    private final CsvSchema schema;
    private final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    public CsvMap(CsvSchema schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        value = convertIfNeeded(key, value);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    private Object convertIfNeeded(String key, Object value) {
        CsvSchema.Column column = schema.column(key);
        if (column.getType() == CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER) {
            try {
                return numberFormat.parse(value.toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // leave it as it is
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

For new type without `no-arg` constructor we should create new `ValueInstantiator`:

```
class CsvMapInstantiator extends ValueInstantiator.Base {

    private final CsvSchema schema;

    public CsvMapInstantiator(CsvSchema schema) {
        super(CsvMap.class);
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    @Override
    public Object createUsingDefault(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return new CsvMap(schema);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canCreateUsingDefault() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CsvApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File csvFile = new File("./resource/test.csv").getAbsoluteFile();

        CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
                .addColumn("firstName", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("lastName", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("age", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .build().withHeader();

        // Create schema aware map module
        SimpleModule csvMapModule = new SimpleModule();
        csvMapModule.addValueInstantiator(CsvMap.class, new CsvMapInstantiator(schema));

        // register map
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.registerModule(csvMapModule);

        // get reader for CsvMap + schema
        ObjectReader objectReaderWithSchema = csvMapper
                .readerWithSchemaFor(CsvMap.class)
                .with(schema);

        MappingIterator<CsvMap> mappingIterator = objectReaderWithSchema.readValues(csvFile);

        while (mappingIterator.hasNext()) {
            CsvMap entryMap = mappingIterator.next();

            Number age = (Number) entryMap.get("age");
            System.out.println(age + " (" + age.getClass() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Above code for below `CSV` payload:

```
firstName,lastName,age
John,Doe,21
Error,Name,-10.1
```

prints:

```
21 (class java.lang.Long)
-10.1 (class java.lang.Double)
```

It looks like a hack but I wanted to show this possibility.

Comment: Thank you Michał. I will look for some alternative solution.

Comment: @IgorLuzhanov, take a look on [csv-parsers-comparison](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) page.

Comment: @IgorLuzhanov, I know you already accepted other answer but maybe you will find something useful anyway.